# How to apply hypothesis or A/B test to 2 distributions obtained using 2 different methods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, ab-test

I am new to running statistical experiments. Thanks for your help in advance.

Suppose now I have 2 different machine learning algorithm to enhance a picture's resolution from a neural networks. The metric I used to measure the output is PSNR, the higher the better.

Now, I run a baseline model over 5000 samples with ground-truth, and got a PSNR distribution; then I applied my model on that same 5000 samples and got another PSNR distribution.

Upon here, I want to validate if my model works no significant difference than the baseline model **because the baseline model is using ground- truth** and in turn my assumption is that if the baseline model is used with raw inputs instead of ground truth, the performance would not be better than ours. But I am still quite confused about how should the pipeline look like. Could you guys please give me some inspirations? Thanks.

The plots for 2 distribution can be found here:
[image]

Comment: What does it mean for "ground-truth" to be used? Both models (the "baseline model" and the "new model") have to be presented with the same inputs as I see it. As it stands, given that both the baseline model and the new model have been applied on the same data, we can directly use something like the [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). If one of the models is given more informative data input it is almost irrelevant to consider a like for like comparison.